# window.location.search.substring is not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html

Could you solve my question please

window.location.search.substring is not working in IE 8

Regards

Ravindran

Comment: Code? No? :( .... \*walking away\*

Comment: There are two _similar but not the same_ functions: `string.substring(from, to)` and `string.substr(start,length)`

Comment: @Christian, @Pavel: Also, `substr()` is non-standard. I recommend `slice()`, which is standardized, universally supported and more flexible than `substring()` by allowing negative indices (e.g. `"purple".slice(-3, -1)` returns "pl")

Answer (score 6):

Maybe related:

Internet explorer (v9 at least, which is what I'm testing here) doesn't fill location.search when there's a hash (#) in front, and packs everything into location.hash instead.

Here's my workaround:

```
var query  = window.location.search.substring(1);
if (!query) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    query = hash.slice(hash.indexOf('?') + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I read that:

> Location objects have a toString method returning the current URL. You can also assign a string to window.location. This means that you can work with window.location as if it were a string in most cases. Sometimes, for example when you need to call a String method on it, you have to explicitly call toString

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

So I'm thinking:

`window.location.search.toString().substring(...)`  ?

Comment: The thing is that MDN speaks for Mozilla and the question is about IE8.

Answer (score 0):

It'll work on Internet Explorer if you change it to document.location.search.substr